# Can somebody explain the difference between IMAP and POP3

Tags: email, smtp, imap

I dunno if I have right understanding or somewhat faulty understanding of the three topics. From a user-end perspective both IMAP or POP3 credentials are what I need if I need to have mail incoming to my e-mail client (let's say Mozilla Thunderbird) while SMTP credentials are needed for outgoing mail. I have read the Wikipedia article on all three and it doesn't tell me which of the two are more widely used and why.

For instance, webmail services such as Gmail used to provide pop3 and smtp the last time I looked

Update: Apparently this was in 90's and now everybody gives IMAP.

Looking to know more.

Comment: "gmail uses pop3 last time I looked"? When was that in the 90s? I have been using IMAP with my googlemail (what it was before they switched to forcing gmail) account for about 10 years now. AFAIK it is IMAP access Thunderbird defaults to, if you configure a googlemail/gmail account in Thunderbird.

Comment: It is possibly that long. It's been quite a long time since I felt the need to move away from webmail but that time seems to be coming.

Comment: Even crappy services like the German t-online and gmx have IMAP support by now. There are good open source imap servers out there, so it has been more and more easy for providers to offer the service.

Answer (score 6):

The biggest difference between POP3 and IMAP from a user's perspective is that POP3 is designed to hold mail until the client (Thunderbird in this case) downloads the mail, at which point it's removed from the POP3 server (it can be configured to do otherwise, but that's not the norm).

IMAP on the other hand, is the opposite.  It is designed to be the client's mail store as the mail generally resides on the server and is accessed from the client (the client will cache the mail locally for performance reasons though).

This means that you can access an IMAP server from more than one client/computer and your mail will be there for you, whereas with a POP3 server the mail will be downloaded by the first client that accesses it and subsequent clients will find no mail.

IMAP also allows you to create folders in your mailbox to manage your mail and again, this will be visible across all clients accessing the mailbox.  POP3 clients can have local folders (within Thunderbird) but they will not be automatically shared as they are not on the server.

The IMAP protocol handles multiple clients reading ("marking as read") and deleting better than POP3 does.

POP3 clients check the server either manually or at set periods (eg every 15min).  IMAP can do the same, but can also receive mail as it's delivered using a feature called IMAP IDLE - a feature that's worth checking is available on your server.

It's not a question of asking the service provider (other than for IMAP IDLE maybe) - it's more of a question of asking yourself how you plan to use the mailbox.